# nginx + vueJS + static landing page

Tags: nginx

I need to open the landing page on `/`, and vueJS application on `/app`. Here is my current nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /app {
            alias /var/www/app/dist/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location / {
            alias /var/www/landing/dist/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

It opens landing on `/`, and vueJS app when I go to `/app`, however, if I open `/app/login` it goes to landing page instead of vue application. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: And which file should be opened in this case? `[..]/app/dist/index.html`?

Comment: Yes, everything starting with `/app` should open `/app/dist/index.html`

Comment: Try: `alias /var/www/app/dist;` without the trailing `/`.

Comment: Returning same result

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith, I removed the trailing `/` + added `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html last;`, the `last` to `/app` and it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no idea why, but adding `last` to vue application configuration fixed it. Here is how the config looks now:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /app {
        alias /var/www/app/dist; # removed the / at the end
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html last; # here is the trick
    }

    location / {
        alias /var/www/landing/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: From http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html - `last` stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI.